# PHP How to remove a specific string/words from the phrase?

Tags: php

This set of strings came from my xml feed. I want to remove the part from PROPERTY FEATURES: to the last. I badly need your help.

```
Semi fitted office for sale in Tower with partition and kichen

    PROPERTY FEATURES: 
    -Basement parking 
    -Central air conditioning 
    -Covered parking
```

should be...

```
Semi fitted office for sale in Tower with partition and kichen
```

Thanks. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/strpos) to get the position of `PROPERTY FEATURES` and use [`substr`](http://www.php.net/substr) to cut the original string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$foundAt = strpos($string, 'PROPERTY FEATURES');
$new = substr($string,0,$foundAt);
echo $new;
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$str = '//your string';
$new = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, 'PROPERTY'));
var_dump($new);
```